# Can't read FileStream into byte[] correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, io, byte, filestream

I have some C# code to call as `TF(true,"C:\input.txt","C:\noexistsyet.file")`, but when I run it, it breaks on `FileStream.Read()` for reading the last chunk of the file into the buffer, getting an index-out-of-bounds `ArgumentException`.

To me, the code seems logical with no overflow for trying to write to the buffer. I thought I had all that set up with `rdlen` and `_chunk`, but maybe I'm looking at it wrong. Any help?

My error: `ArgumentException was unhandled: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.`

```
public static bool TF(bool tf, string filepath, string output)
    {
        long _chunk = 16 * 1024; //buffer count
        long total_size = 0
        long rdlen = 0;
        long wrlen = 0;
        long full_chunks = 0;
        long end_remain_buf_len = 0;
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filepath);
        total_size = fi.Length;
        full_chunks = total_size / _chunk;
        end_remain_buf_len = total_size % _chunk;
        fi = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);
        FileStream fw = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create);
        for (long chunk_pass = 0; chunk_pass < full_chunks; chunk_pass++)
        {
            int chunk = (int)_chunk * ((tf) ? (1 / 3) : 3); //buffer count for xbuffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[_chunk];
            byte[] xbuffer = new byte[(buffer.Length * ((tf) ? (1 / 3) : 3))];
            //Read chunk of file into buffer
            fs.Read(buffer, (int)rdlen, (int)_chunk); //ERROR occurs here
            //xbuffer = do stuff to make it *3 longer or *(1/3) shorter;
            //Write xbuffer into chunk of completed file
            fw.Write(xbuffer, (int)wrlen, chunk);
            //Keep track of location in file, for index/offset
            rdlen += _chunk;
            wrlen += chunk;
        }
        if (end_remain_buf_len > 0)
        {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[end_remain_buf_len];
                byte[] xbuffer = new byte[(buffer.Length * ((tf) ? (1 / 3) : 3))];
                fs.Read(buffer, (int)rdlen, (int)end_remain_buf_len); //error here too
                //xbuffer = do stuff to make it *3 longer or *(1/3) shorter;
                fw.Write(xbuffer, (int)wrlen, (int)end_remain_buf_len * ((tf) ? (1 / 3) : 3));
                rdlen += end_remain_buf_len;
                wrlen += chunk;
        }
        //Close opened files
        fs.Close();
        fw.Close();
        return false; //no functionality yet lol
    }
```

Comment: What about Stream.Copy or File.Copy?

Comment: Learn to love `using `blocks.

Comment: You should reconsider the method/parameter name `TF`/`tf`. Who would _dare_ call `TF` with `tf` false?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Code was an example. My saved file isn't actually called using TF(*,*,*), I just put TF there as an example. Same with the non-functioning return false/true;
@BenVoigt: I see the helpful code `using` them down below, this is probably the 5th or 6th rewrite of my code being that I was using `using` at one point when other files in my code were different.
And @usr the Copy functions I believe have their own chunk sizes but I'm sure it wouldn't matter to me, I'll have to see about incorporating those if I need to
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Read()` method of `Stream` (the base class of `FileStream`) returns an `int` indicating the number of bytes read, and 0 when it has no more bytes to read, so you don't even need to know the file size beforehand:

```
public static void CopyFileChunked(int chunkSize, string filepath, string output)
{
    byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];

    using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open))
    using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create))
    {
        int bytes;
        while ((bytes = reader.Read(chunk , 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
        {
            writer.Write(chunk, 0, bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Or even `File.Copy()` may do the trick, if you can live with letting the framework decide about the chunk size.

Comment: This works awesome man! Thanks for your help! Merged this part of the code into mine perfectly on first try ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's failing on this line:

```
  fw.Write(xbuffer, (int)wrlen, chunk);
```

You are declaring xbuffer as

```
 byte[] xbuffer = new byte[(buffer.Length * ((tf) ? (1 / 3) : 3))];
```

Since `1 / 3` is an integer division, it returns 0.And you are declaring `xbuffer` with the size 0 hence the error.You can fix it by casting one of the operand to a floating point type or using literals.But then you still need to cast the result back to integer.

```
 byte[] xbuffer = new byte[(int)(buffer.Length * ((tf) ? (1m / 3) : 3))];
```

The same problem also present in the `chunk` declaration.

Comment: I ended up going with `(tf) ? (Length / 3) : (Length * 3))` to get rid of the int/float problem in getting .333 with (1/3), this works since I know that `Length` will be a multiple of 3 or to be multiplied by 3 depending on tf being true or false;
Thanks!